# Test between a Yes/No independent variable and a continuous Age variable?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, binary-data, continuous-data

Sorry if this is very easy but I have been struggling all day. 
I have some data where I know the ages of 16 subjects:

3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,7,9

and the corresponding answer:

Y,Y,Y,N,N,Y,Y,Y,Y,N,N,N,Y,N,N,N

and I keep reaching different conclusions! I am trying to see if there is a difference between the age and whether a Yes or No answer was given.
I got as far as thinking t-test but would it be paired/unpaired etc?

Comment: What would the pairing be?  There is none evident in the data as you have described them.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on which is the outcome variable. If age is, maybe do a kruskal wallace test. You could do a t-test (not paired) but the discrete nature of age doesn't make the normal assumption very reasonable.

If Yes/No is the outcome, then do logistic regression with age as the predictor

Spoiler alert: I just checked, and you won't get a significant result either way you do it. The $p$-value for the logistic regression is about 0.16, for the kruskal-wallace test it's about 0.21, and for the two-sample t-test it's about 0.14